# How to use jquery to remove <div> in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a few rows surrounded by a div, but it doesn't work, why?

```
$(function(){
  $("#div1").empty();
});


           <table id="tbl" border="1px">
                <thead>
                   ...
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblBody">
                    <div id="div1">
                        <tr id="tr1">
                            <td>
                                row1
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                row2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I assume you html and javascript are in the appropriate separate files/tags? Show us the complete code you're using. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no such thing as rows surrounded by a `<div>`. It is invalid to put a `<div>` inside a `<tbody>`, so the browser tries to ‘fix’ your mistake by kicking the `<div>` out of the table, putting it somewhere else in the document tree you didn't expect it to be, and making sure it does not contain any `<tr>`​s. So when you empty it, it has no contents to lose.

This is what multiple `<tbody>`​s are for.